# OCMock: testing a method with an NSDictionary argument being invoked

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary, ocmock

I have the following classes:

```
@interface ReportsArchiver

-(void)fileReport:(NSDictionary*)reports;

@end

@interface OfficeManager

@property (nonatomic) ReportsArchiver* reportsArchiver;
-(void) reportIncident:(NSString*)name description:(NSString*)description;

@end
```

Using OCMock I want to test that when invoking `[officeManager reportIncident:@"fire alarm" description: @"false fire alarm"]` then `[officeManager.reportsArchiver fileReport]` gets invoked with the dictionary `@{@"name": @"fire alarm", @"description": @"false fire alarm"}`.

So far I've written the following code to do so:

```
OfficeManager* officeManager = [OfficeManager new];
id reportsArchiverMock = OCMClassMock([ReportsArchiver class]);
officeManager.reportsArchiver = reportsArchiverMock;
NSDictionary* expectedReportDictionary = @{@"name": @"fire alarm", @"description": @"false fire alarm"};

[officeManager reportIncident:@"fire alarm" description: @"false fire alarm"];

// This call will fail because it checks for object equality, not dictionary equality.    
OCMVerify([reportsArchiverMock fileReport:expectedReportDictionary]);
```

How can I verify that the `[reportsArchiverMock fileReport:{(NSDictionary*)]` is invoked with an identical NSDictionary using OCMock?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since then I got suggestions from @wolffan and @catehstn over Twitter and here are the solutions I found.

1. Using `OCMExpect` - unlike `OCMVerify`, `OCMExpect` compares `NSDictionaries` correctly. This is the cleanest solution I've found.

   ```
   OfficeManager* officeManager = [OfficeManager new];
   id reportsArchiverMock = OCMClassMock([ReportsArchiver class]);
   officeManager.reportsArchiver = reportsArchiverMock;
   NSDictionary* expectedReportDictionary = @{@"name": @"fire alarm", @"description": @"false fire alarm"};

   OCMExpect([reportsArchiverMock fileReport:expectedReportDictionary])
   [officeManager reportIncident:@"fire alarm" description: @"false fire alarm"];

   OCMVerifyAll(reportsArchiverMock);
   ```
2. Using `OCMStub` and checking the argument in a callback. This is a pretty messy solution.

.

```
OfficeManager* officeManager = [OfficeManager new]
id reportsArchiverMock = OCMClassMock([ReportsArchiver class]);
officeManager.reportsArchiver = reportsArchiverMock;
NSDictionary* expectedReportDictionary = @{@"name": @"fire alarm", @"description": @"false fire alarm"};            

void (^reportIncidentInvocation)(NSInvocation *) = ^(NSInvocation *invocation) {
       __unsafe_unretained NSInvocationOperation *reportDictionary;
       [invocation getArgument: &reportDictionary atIndex: 2];
       XCTAssertTrue([expectedPropertiesCollection isEqualToDictionary:(NSDictionary*)reportDictionary]);
    };
OCMStub([officeManager reportIncident:[OCMArg any]]).andDo(reportIncidentInvocation);

OCMVerify([reportsArchiverMock fileReport:expectedReportDictionary]);
```

Comment: This is odd. There should be no difference using verify or expect. If there is an issue with object equality vs dictionary equality then that should occur with expect, too. (And I say this as the maintainer of OCMock.) Would you mind opening an issue on Github, preferrably with a failing unit test against OCMock?

Comment: Thanks for the response @ErikDoernenburg. I'll try to repro this with a unit test and open an issue.